# Capture traffic sent over Wi-Fi Aware (NAN) using Wireshark

Tags: android-studio, sockets, wireshark, pcap, wifi-direct

I have created a Wi-Fi Aware application in Android studio that uses Wi-Fi Aware for connectivity and enables chat messaging between two phones using socket programing. I would like to inspect the chat messages that are transmitted between the phones. I used my Macbook Air in sniff mode to capture the packets sent on channel 149 (5 GHz).

The first part of the capture is the setup of NAN (Wi-Fi Aware) connection with the NAN handshake. After this part, messages are being sent between the phones. I cannot see any clear indication of this in Wireshark. The MAC addresses of the phones are 02:5f:07:88:a8:ba and 02:ce:3f:b6:35:64. Packet numbers 173 - 178 frames marked Block Ack. This packet pattern (6 Block Acks) occur every time a message is sent between the phones, so I know that messages are in fact being sent.

My question is, why can´t I see the data packets transmitted between the phones in the pcap file?

[image: pcap1]
[image: pcap2]

Comment: can you kindly please share the source code, am also working on creating simple wifi-aware chat application.